# Walking through values in a dictionary of lists

Tags: python, list, dictionary

I have a dictionary of lists of unequal length, and I'd like to step through it taking the first value of each list, then the second, then the third, etc, generating a master list of the values in order, like so:

```
dict = {
    ('List1',): [("value1"), ("value2"), ("value3")],
    ('List2',): [("value1"), ("value2"), ("value3"), ("value4")],
    ('List3',): [("value1"), ("value2")]
}
```

I'd like to be able to walk through this and create a new list with all of the value1s in order, then all of the value2s, then any value3s and then the value4.

How to do this, though, is completely baffling me, so any advice would be greatly appreciated. My actual dictionary is much larger than this, and gets up to hundreds of values in some of the lists.

I've seen some answers about moving through lists in parallel, but nothing about those lists being inside a dictionary, with keys that also must be iterated.

Comment: Please see the first linked duplicate for the technique to iterate in the right order, and understand that `zip` can accept any number of arguments. See the second to understand how to pass all the dict values as separate arguments.